# Bug in WildFly http-remoting

Tags: wildfly, wildfly-8

When I access remote EJB, the login credentials are passed into the custom security domain that is set for all EJBs. Here password is received in my custom login module as org.jboss.as.security.remoting.RemotingConnectionCredential@35ddbd0f.

But when login from browser, password is received as entered. What's wrong with remote calls?

Here is my jndi.properties

```
    java.naming.factory.initial=org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory
    java.naming.provider.url=http-remoting://localhost:8080
    java.naming.security.principal=xxxx
    java.naming.security.credentials=xxxx
    jboss.naming.client.ejb.context=true
```

I checked with latest stable version 8.2.0.